# Big difference between send_request_date and sent_date in sysmail_sentitems after running sp_send_dbmail,

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

A send DB mail process was executed on Friday:

1. placed on the mail queue at 2016-03-04 12:21:22.937,
2. it wasn't sent until 2016-03-04 16:00:01.000, 1311 seconds later.

Usually `DATEDIFF(SECOND,send_request_date,sent_date)` is at most a few seconds. What could have caused this massive time gap?

Diagnosed via

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(SECOND,send_request_date,sent_date) 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems;
```

Comment: I fail to see what, exactly, this has to do with databases? Isn't it more to do with your mail server?

Comment: there were no issues with the  mail server at the time

Answer (score 0):

Network Communication or a problem with the mailserver would be my guess. Check the log for the Mail server during this period. Chanses are you'll find it was unavailiable.
Regards Marten

Comment: We use gmail, there were NO issues with the mailserver or the network at this time